# Deserializeing JSON array in Swift 4

Tags: arrays, json, swift, serialization, swift4

I've been fiddling around with my structs for hours just trying different things but cant get them to work properly (the User struct is working fine). From the provided JSON the only thing I need is `"value"`. If anyone could enlighten me on why this isn't working and how I could make it work it would be greatly appreciated!

Error:

> `Values of type '[Properties]' has no member 'value'`

JSON:

```
{
  "id": "e58d7f751c7f498085a79a37bf22f20b",
  "name": "Rhidlor",
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "textures",
      "value": "eyJ0aW1lc3RhbXAiOjE1MDk1MjQxNzExODMsInByb2ZpbGVJZCI6ImU1OGQ3Zjc1MWM3ZjQ5ODA4NWE3OWEzN2JmMjJmMjBiIiwicHJvZmlsZU5hbWUiOiJSaGlkbG9yIiwidGV4dHVyZXMiOnsiU0tJTiI6eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwOi8vdGV4dHVyZXMubWluZWNyYWZ0Lm5ldC90ZXh0dXJlLzExMzdiODY3YjRhMmZiNTkzY2Y2ZDA1ZDgyMTA5MzdjYzc4YmM5ZTA1NThhZDYzZDQxY2M4ZWMyZjk5ZTdkNjMifX19"
    }
  ]
}
```

Swift:

```
import UIKit

struct User: Decodable {
var id: String?
}

struct Skin: Decodable {
private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
    case properties = "properties"
}

var properties: [Properties]
}

struct Properties: Decodable {
var value: String?
}

class PlayerViewController: UIViewController {
var username: String?
var skinUrl: String?
var properties = [Properties]()
var skin: Skin!
var user: User!

@IBOutlet var uuidLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var skinImageView: UIImageView!

@IBAction func usernameTextField(_ sender: UITextField) {
    username = sender.text!
    parseJson(username: username!)
}

func decodeSkinValue(){
    print("decode fired")
    if let decodedData = Data(base64Encoded: properties.value), //getting error on this row
        let decodedString = String(data: decodedData, encoding: .utf8){
        skinUrl = decodedString
        print(skinUrl!)
    }
}

func setValues(){
    print("set values fired")
    uuidLabel.text = user.id!
}

func invalidUsernameError(){
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid Name", message: "The name you specified could not be found", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func parseJson(username: String){
    let jsonUrlString = "https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/" + username
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {
        print("guard let url failed")
        return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data else {
            print("guard let data failed")
            return
        }

        do {
            print("user do fired")
            self.user = try JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: data)
            if self.user.id != nil {
                self.parseSkinJson()
            } else {
                self.invalidUsernameError()
            }
        }
        catch let jsonError {
            print("Error serializing json: ", jsonError)
            self.invalidUsernameError()
        }

        }.resume()

}

func parseSkinJson(){
    let jsonUrlString = "https://sessionserver.mojang.com/session/minecraft/profile/" + user.id!
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {
        print("guard let url failed")
        return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data else {
            print("guard let data failed")
            return
        }

        do {
            print("skill do fired")
            self.skin = try JSONDecoder().decode(Skin.self, from: data)
            self.properties = self.skin.properties
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("others funcs fired")
                print(properties.value!) //getting error on this row
                self.decodeSkinValue()
                self.setValues()
            }
        }
        catch let jsonError{
            print("Error serializing json: ", jsonError)
        }

    }.resume()

}

}
```

Comment: you've created `properties` named array, if there is going to be only one value in `properties` then you can access it like this, `self.properties[0].value`

Comment: Nooooooo, that was the solution!?! Jeez I feel dumb, but thanks so much for the help!